# Angular route links not working as expected from Array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

When I hard code some routerLinks into my application it works fine e.g

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
```

But If I do the following, the routerLinks work but refresh the page every time I navigate around my app:

**View:**

```
<ul class="list navbar-nav"></ul>
```

**Ts.file**

```
public links = [
    {
      name: "Home",
      route: "/home"
    },
    {
      name: "page",
      route: "/page"
    }
  ];

  public looper = () => {
    let items = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) {
      items += `<a class="nav-item links mr-4 mt-2" href=""${
        this.links[i].route
      }" routerLink="${this.links[i].route}">${this.links[i].name}</a>`;
    }
    return items;
  };

  public insertLinks = () => {
    let target = document.querySelector(".list");
    target.innerHTML = this.looper();
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.insertLinks();
  }
}
```

I know this may not be the Angualr way of working, but any reason why it refreshes each time?

Comment: You seem adding href attribute to your anchor tag, this will refresh the page despite having the routerLinks added to it!

Comment: @Sole, you can not create a "html on fly" that include Angular directives (routerLink is an Angular directive) because Angular not "compile" the .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be better approached from the `template` perspective. I think this may work better for you. Iterate your links with `ngFor` and bind the value to the `routerLink`. Accessing the DOM from the component class should be avoided.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let l of links;">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" [routerLink]="l.route">{{ l.name }}</a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Maybe that was the Angular way. I suppose the way I had it was the Vanilla JS way.

Comment: Glad to hear, and technically you can put the ngFor on the a tag, no need for the ng-container - cheers